# Is there a way to publish map server by command on ArcGIS Server 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, map-service

I create a service define file by ArcMap10.1, but it's very large(about 90G).

Now I want to publish it to Server by Server Manager(access Brower).

Unfortunately, the manager is always time out (maybe the sd file is very large).

Is there another way to publish the map server?

Comment: A 90Gb .sd file?  You've got to find another way.  You'll need to register data store(s) so that the publishing process is not cluttered with data.

Comment: Thanks @Vince. I will try to recreate my sd files. Maybe there is some error when I save the server define file. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 2 GB file size limit which is set by web browsers Firefox/IE. You should use Google Chrome. From [Esri Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01540000043p000000):

> If the service definition you are publishing includes source GIS
>   datasets, the size of the data and your network bandwidth will impact
>   the time it takes to publish. Service definitions over 2 GB in size
>   cannot be published using the Internet Explorer or Firefox web
>   browsers. It's recommended that you use Google Chrome for service
>   definitions over 2 GB.

If you have access to ArcGIS Server from your ArcMap, try publishing from ArcMap and see if it works. I have never published any service that was larger than a couple of GBs.

And I do agree with Vince, you *should* review your workflow. Maybe there is a chance you could publish a map service that will reference to the data source stored somewhere (such as your large enterprose geodatabase or a huge mosaic dataset stored on a shared folder on a server).

Copying large data to the server will result in problems later on when the data was changed/updated and then you will often need to re-publish the service which would imply copying 90GB again and this takes time.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. There is some error when I save the server define file. I will try another way.